# convert data from json to the given format

Tags: javascript, php, json, api

I am working with an API where I have to give input from a `json` file.

my json file looks like this

```
{
  "cases":[
    { 
        "case_no":1,
        "case_input":"Test 1",
        "case_output":"Test 1"
    },
    { 
        "case_no":2,
        "case_input":"Test 2",
        "case_output":"Test 2"
    } 
        ]       
}
```

I want to extract `case_input` from this json and need to convert it like this

```
$testcases = "[\"Test 1\", \"Test 2\"]";
```

How can I do this using javascript or php?

At present what I have done is import JSON through Ajax then

```
var testcases = [];
                  for(var j in data.cases ){
                    testcases[j]= data.cases[j].case_input;
                  }
                  testcase = JSON.stringify(testcases);
```

Answer (score 1):

In php, you can use `array_column()` to extract these values.  You only need to decode the json before then encode the result.

```
$json='{
  "cases":[
    { 
        "case_no":1,
        "case_input":"Test 1",
        "case_output":"Test 1"
    },
    { 
        "case_no":2,
        "case_input":"Test 2",
        "case_output":"Test 2"
    } 
        ]       
}';
$array=json_decode($json,true);
$case_inputs=array_column($array['cases'],'case_input');
echo json_encode($case_inputs);
// Output: ["Test 1","Test 2"]
```

Or if you need the literal string with the escaped double quotes:

```
$array=json_decode($json,true);
$case_inputs=array_column($array['cases'],'case_input');
echo '[\"',implode('\", \"',$case_inputs),'\"]';
// output: [\"Test 1\", \"Test 2\"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.map:

```
var v = {
  "cases":[
    { 
        "case_no":1,
        "case_input":"Test 1",
        "case_output":"Test 1"
    },
    { 
        "case_no":2,
        "case_input":"Test 2",
        "case_output":"Test 2"
    } 
        ]       
}
var testcases = v.cases.map((i) => i.case_input)
```